# Encoding cannot be loaded

Tags: phalanger

I'm having a problem with Phalanger 3.0 running as a console app on Mono 4.0.1

Program.php

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

Compile

```
$mono phpc.exe Program.php /out:Program.exe
```

Run

```
$mono Program.exe
```

Output

```
Encoding cannot be loaded.
fileEncoding=""
Hello world
```

Is there any configurations am I missing or is it normal?

Comment: First of all, you can update to Phalanger 4.0 which has several Mono-related fixes.

Comment: Then, it is possible, in configuration (app.config or machine.config), there is <globalization fileEncoding=""> which causes Phalanger to look for empty encoding name.

Comment: I've upgraded to Phalanger 4.0 but the problem still persisted.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, The config <globalization fileEncoding=""> does the trick